# Earth-Oblateness-Effect and advance of the apogee?

Tags: earth, axis

in our literature it says that the results of the Earth-Oblateness-Effect are as follows:

- A regression of the nodes
- An advance of the perigee

regarding this i got 2 questions: 
1.) What about the apogee? does it not advance?
2.) An advance of the perigee means an advance of the semi-major axis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. What about the apogee? does it not advance?

Of course it advances. Apogee still occurs about half an orbit away from perigee. I wrote "about" because the anomaly change from perigee to apogee (or apogee to perigee) is no longer exactly 180°, but it is very, very close to that number.

> 2. An advance of the perigee means an advance of the semi-major axis?

Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much !